# Upgrading an old Toshiba

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, motherboard

My old Toshiba Satellite L500 13w is becoming slower. 
I have had few problems with it until now, it's been pretty reliable since I first bought it - brand new - about ten years ago.

I changed the Rams for two 2GB ones, the HDD for a SSD, and it was doing really well until a couple of months ago.

It now refuses to load City Skylines, slows down when I am using Scrivener and open the online Thesaurus, and at times will suddenly disconnect the wifi and force me to use the Ethernet cable.

I was wondering if it would be worth to change the cpu cores, or any other elements on the poor old guy, or if I should simply save for a brand new laptop.

I can do a few things - simple ones - like changing the rams and drives, and install new OSs, but am not much good at the rest, like knowing what is worth doing or not. For that reason I would appreciate solid advice from people who know the things I don't :)

Thanks.

Comment: The *sudden* performance loss is probably OS related.
Consider reinstalling Windows and stress testing the CPU to see if you can achieve the performance you expect.

Comment: towe will it handle windows10?

Comment: If a reinstall doesn't recover any performance then you can also clean the laptop, replace the CPU fan, and reapply thermal compound. Many older laptops get slower because of CPU throttling, they aren't able to cool themselves like they used to.